# How to set timeout on alert message?

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Statement**

I would like to set a timeout on the alert message if the user didn't close the box within 15 seconds.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
     <div id="Alert" class="alert alert-<?=$_SESSION['msg_type']?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span style="font-size:1em;">&times;</span></button>
          <center><?php echo $_SESSION['message'];?></center>
          <?php unset($_SESSION['message']); ?>
     </div>
<?php endif ?>

<script>
//set timeout here...
</script>
```

Comment: setTimeout function from jquery

Comment: try $(".classname").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
    $(".classname").slideUp(500);
})